# Defining Callback function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set error validation for `strn` and is needed to follow this strict rule,but as I am unaware of how to use callback functionality, can anybody help me in setting up the form validation for the same?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('strn', 'STRN', 'trim|callback_strn_check');
```

and the strict rules are:-

- The STRN is a unique 15 digit number.
- 1st ten digits are PAN number of the Assessee
- 11th & 12th is the Service Tax Code (Its is either ST or SD)

One more important point is that this field is not mandatory, yet if user fills it inappropriately, then he should receive a form error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('strn', 'STRN','trim|max_length[15]|min_length[15]callback_strn_check');


function strn_check($num){
    if(strlen($num) != 15){
        return false;
    } else if(substr($num, -2) == "SD" || substr($num, -2) == "ST") {
        $ten = substr($num, 0, 10);
        if(ctype_digit($ten))
            return true;
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For the first 10 characters to be same as `pan` you can do like this,

```
function strn_check($num){
    if(strlen($num) != 15){
        return false;
    } else if(substr($num, -2) == "SD" || substr($num, -2) == "ST") {
        $ten = substr($num, 0, 10);
        if($this->input->post("pan") == $ten)
            return true;
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want you can use `strtolower()`, if case doesnt have any influence in validation. As of now, it will work only for uppercase letters(last 2 characters).

Comment: and what about the first ten digits to be same as PAN which is also an input from the user?

Comment: all characters shud be same?? or all characters shud be digits??

Comment: that should be exactly the same as the one entered in pan

code:-   $pan = $this->input->post('pan');
used in controller

Comment: you can use `matches` a default in form validation

Comment: if you want first 10 characters to be digits, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

i tried the answer given above and fixed few bugs,now its working absolutely perfect.
here is the code:-

```
function strn_check($num)
{
    if($num != "")
    {
        if(strlen($num) != 15)
        {
            return false;
        } 
        else if(substr($num, 10,12) != "SD" || substr($num, 10,12) != "ST") 
        {
            $ten = substr($num, 0, 10);
            if($this->input->post("pan") != $ten)
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```